# Powershell - Accessing data within Properties from Get-ChildItems

Tags: powershell, get-childitem, registrykey

I'm new to powershell and thought I'd start practicing.

I've created a new key in Registry Editor. Now, I'm trying to access this data from the Get-ChildItems commands.

I specifically want the Email within the Property column and hopefully save it as a string variable, see
[image: Powershell Output]

The above output is shown when the below command is executed:

`Get-ChildItem -Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Linkage\Sort'`

So far, I've tried (to no avail): ~

`$PropertyObject = Get-ChildItem -Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Linkage\Sort' | Select-Object Property`

`Write-Host $PropertyObject`

This only lists the directory names, and not the content.

Please help?

Comment: Instead of piping to `Select-Object Property` try `Get-ItemProperty` instead.

Comment: Get-ItemPropertyValue done the trick. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `Get-ChildItem`, use the `Get-ItemPropertyValue` cmdlet.

```
Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path $Path -Name Email
```